# Getting controller undefined when trying to run jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-e2e, karma-jasmine

I'm just about to write tests for my angularjs-app. However when Im trying to run the test which is very simpel one i get the following error.

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MyPageController' is not a function, got undefined
```

I'll provide code for the setup of my controllers, config etc.

**Route**

```
var myPageApp = angular.module('myPageApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'app.controller', 'app.service', 'app.filter', 'app.config'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'App_AngularJs/partials/myPage/myPage.htm',
        controller: 'MyPageController',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
    });
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
var myPageApp = angular.module('app.controller', ['oci.treeview', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('MyPageController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', '$timeout', '$filter', '$modal', 'myPageService',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, $timeout, $filter, $modal, myPageService) {
        init();

        function init() {
            $scope.page = { value: $routeParams.page || 1 };
        }
}]);
```

**Simpel test**

```
'use strict';

describe('Testing MyPageController', function(){

   var scope;

//mock Application to allow us to inject our own dependencies
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myPageApp'));

//mock the controller for the same reason and include $rootScope and $controller
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
    //create an empty scope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    //declare the controller and inject our empty scope
    $controller('MyPageController', { $scope: scope });
}));

// tests start here
it('should map routes to controllers', function () {
    module('myPageApp');

      inject(function ($route) {

          expect($route.routes['/'].controller).toBe('MyPageController');
          expect($route.routes['/'].templateUrl).
            toEqual('App_AngularJs/partials/myPage/myPage.htm');
      });
   });

   it('should have variable assigned = "1"', function(){
       expect(scope.page.value).toBe(1);
   });
});
```

My wildest and best guess is that i need to mock app.controller but how? Everything starts out with myPageApp which holds references to service, controller etc etc..

Comment: Try adding a `beforeEach(module('app.controller'));` before the `myPageApp` one.

Comment: @JesusRodriguez I tryed it out but still same error.
I just saw that futher down in the error message is says also..
    Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that routing and the controller are trying to load different modules viz "myPageApp" and "app.controller" and in your test with beforeEach you are trying to load 'myPageApp' module to which router is associated but not the controller.

So it seems to me that either you use same module for both router and controllers. Or try loading both modules in the test. Still I believe associating the router and controller with same module makes more sense.

An small example as below. Extract the application module in common js file (may be call it app.js)

```
var myApp = angular.module(
'myApp');
```

Now define router as

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/testUrl', {
        templateUrl: '/myApp/views/test-view',
        controller: 'TestViewController'
    })
```

Similary define controller as

```
myApp.controller('TestViewController',[your dependencies goes here])
```

And now in your tests

```
beforeEach(module('myApp'));
```

This will work for sure. Hope it helps.